# Не обновляется категория в MediaWiki

Tags: php, postgresql, mediawiki

Последовательность действий:

1. Создаю страницу
2. В самом низу пишу [[Category:Моя Категория]]
3. Сохраняю

После сохранения, плашка с категориями не появляется. Если явно перейти в категорию, то страница там тоже отсутствует.

Для того, чтобы все заработало, иду в папку **maintenance** и в консоли выполняю:

```
php refreshLinks.php
```

После выполнения этой команды плашка с категориями появляется на странице и, также, сама страница начинает отображаться в списке страниц категории.

Почему ссылки не обновляются автоматически?

**MediaWiki 1.28**

**Субд PostgreSql 9.6**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что кэширование. Прежде чем отдавать данные, они сохраняются в cache, для быстродействия и избежания ошибок исполняемого кода.

Можете отключить его добавив в Ваш `LocalSettings.php`следующие строки:

```
$wgEnableParserCache = false;
$wgCachePages = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Кеш можно не отключать. Достаточно сбросить кеш на конкретной странице. В меню страницы есть пункт Purge cache.